# Find the highest power of $5$ that divides $518!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find the highest power of $5$ that divides $518!$

I haven't even been able to begin on this problem. How can I start to solve problems like this?

Comment: Thank you sir I have got it!

Comment: In the future start searching first or try to start a bit yourself together with searching.

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$518! := 518\cdot 517 \cdot 516 \cdot \dots \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$

Without any formulae you have to count the numbers lower thn $518$ that are divisible for $5$, $25$, $125$:

$ 5 \ | \ 5, 10, 15, 20, \dots$

$ 25 \ | \ 25, 50, 75, 100, \dots $

$ 125 \ | \ 125, 250, 375, 500 $

So in the first row we have $\Big \lfloor \frac{518}{5} \Big\rfloor$, for the second row $\Big \lfloor \frac{518}{25} \Big\rfloor$ and for the last $\Big \lfloor \frac{518}{125} \Big\rfloor$. Sum this numbers and there you got your answer

**Edit:**

You can see that $25 = 5\cdot 5$ so you could reply "Why do I have to count the numbers that are divided by $25$ just once and not twice?".

The answer is simple: you count them only once because numbers that are divided by $25$ have already been counted once when considering the multiples of $5$

Answer (score 2):

From [Challenge and Thrill of Pre-College Mathematics](https://books.google.at/books?id=SnvBeodeTDcC&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq=Find+the+highest+power+of+5+that+divides+518!&source=bl&ots=Tz--iy_Fro&sig=ACfU3U1kgKxWb59VKbAyU-DiYdD1c8ioXA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiIsJnuhJznAhVHbVAKHdKUCZ4Q6AEwEnoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=Find%20the%20highest%20power%20of%205%20that%20divides%20518!&f=false):

The highest power of $5$ less than $518$ is $5^3=125$. Therefore the highest power of $5$ divising $518!$ is
$$
\left[\frac{518}{5}\right]+\left[\frac{518}{25}\right]+\left[\frac{518}{125}\right]=103+20+4=127.
$$

Comment: You beat me on time. I starded writing but then I realized I did not know how to implement the floor function. However good quote

Answer (score 0):

For more general result, click [Here]https://proofwiki.org/wiki/De_Polignac%27s_Formula, it is called De Polignac's formula.